# Why is a duplicate random string generated by C# method

Tags: c#

The following method generates a random string with the given length.

When executed twice in a row, the same string is given. Is anybody able to shed any light on why this might be?

```
 public static string GenerateRandomString(int size, bool lowerCase)
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            Random random = new Random();
            char ch;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                ch = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(26 * random.NextDouble() + 65)));
                builder.Append(ch);
            }
            if (lowerCase)
                return builder.ToString().ToLower();
            return builder.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: btw, `(char)random.Next(65, 91)` is a much easier way to get a random A-Z - maybe even `(char)(random.Next(26) + (int)(lowerCase ? 'a' : 'A'))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not using `Random` correctly.

When calling your `GenerateRandomString` in a tight loop, it will end up being seeded to the same value many times.

I suggest reading [Random numbers](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter12/Random.aspx) from the C# in depth site, by Jon Skeet.

Here is the suggested way to get a `Random` instance:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;



public static class RandomProvider
{    
    private static int seed = Environment.TickCount;

    private static ThreadLocal<Random> randomWrapper = new ThreadLocal<Random>(() =>
        new Random(Interlocked.Increment(ref seed))
    );

    public static Random GetThreadRandom()
    {
        return randomWrapper.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you give me any guidance on how to improve this method?

Comment: @Nick - The post I linked to has a good overview and solution.

Comment: We are using this code but are getting duplicate values occasionally. The only thing I see different is we're using a static property instead of a static method as in `public static Random Random { get { return randomWrapper.Value; } }` That shouldn't cause trouble, should it?

Answer (score 2):

Create your random object static

```
public class MyClass
{
   public static Random rand = new Random();

   public int MyMethod()
   {
       return rand.Next() % 10 + 1;
   }
}
```

Random works on `System.DatTime.Now.Ticks`.

If we do like this

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

internally it happens as

```
Random rand = new Random(System.DateTime.Now.Ticks);
```

Just think for a moment the only think which is not constant in system is System Time.

When ever using Random class make its object once and use its method `Next()` where ever you want. You will find this situation in loops when random object is created inside loops.

In your code they are created one after another, they get created by same Ticks seed value.

Create your random object static and then they won't be same.

Comment: Note that Random isn't thread-safe. If that's used from multiple threads, you can easily "break" an instance, leaving it returning 0 forever.

Answer (score 1):

Executed twice in a row how *fast* ? the seed of Random is time-dependent, so if you're testing programmaticaly, this could happen. I'd create the Random object elsewhere *once*, then refer to it in the method.

Answer (score 1):

Move your `Random` object outside the method so that the same one will be used on repeated calls.

```
static Random random = new Random();
```

The problem with what you've got now is that the `Random` class uses the current time as its seed value, so if it is created twice in rapid succession, both will have the same seed, and so produce the same random string.

Comment: See my comment on Romil's answer.